# How to animate input control border color smoothly - twice

Tags: jquery, animation, colors, border, jquery-animate

I would like to animate an input control border where it changes colour twice using a smooth animation.

What do I need to add to the code below to add another animation to make it change colour again (to say #FF0?).

When I add a second animiation to the code below, jQuery appears to 'reset' the border colour rather than smoothly animating.

$('#searchinput').click(function() {
    $('#searchinput').animate({borderColor: '#36C'}, 400)

});

Comment: Are you using some jQuery plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some bug in jQuery UI library. If you animate `borderColor`, it doesn't properly detect old value of border color. However, if you use `borderLeftColor`, `borderTopColor` etc., it works correctly. I suggest you to use this code to fix your issue:

```
$.fn.border_color_animate = function(color, time, callback) {
  var obj = {};
  $(["Left", "Right", "Top", "Bottom"]).each(function() {
   obj["border"+this+"Color"] = color;
  });
  this.animate(obj, time, callback);
};

$('#searchinput').click(function() {
  $('#searchinput').border_color_animate('#36C', 400, function() {
    $('#searchinput').border_color_animate('#f00',400);
  });
});
```

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/riateche/nGfud/)